# dev express How to align radio and its content in WPF

Tags: wpf, radio-button, styles, themes, devexpress-wpf

Am using devexpress wpf tools version 17.1. I am using Light Gray theme in the application.
Here is my xaml for radio buttons

```
         <RadioButton Content="Forms"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       GroupName="ActionGroup"/>
         <RadioButton Content="All Questions"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      GroupName="ActionGroup"/>

         <RadioButton Content="Current Question"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      GroupName="ActionGroup"/>
```

Here is the output
[image]

the content is top aligned, want to make it center with image. I placed these radio buttons in dx:GroupFrame, the groupframe header also has the same problem, header is stop aligned.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set the VerticalContentAlignment Property of the RadioButtons to Center?

Something along this lines:

```
<RadioButton Content="Current Question"
   Grid.Row="2"
   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
   GroupName="ActionGroup"/>
```

Comment: tried with margin, padding, verticalContentAlignment, textAlignment nothing is working